# Why am I the owner of the chatroom?

Tags: support, chat

So I talk a lot...

Is this enough reason to give me ownership on the chatroom? Is this ownership going to last until manual removal or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80205/chat-clean-up-owner-rules/80208#80208) – to make sure that an active room has an active owner, this [may happen automatically](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/36?m=1640418#1640418).

Whether you do anything with that or not is up to you (being a room owner isn't really a huge responsibility). You could also appoint someone else as a room owner, if they are more inclined to be one.

Finally, you can also remove yourself from the owner list again if you want (just set yourself to "no special access" on the [room's access control page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics?tab=access)). You might want to make some other regular user the owner before this, because if you don't, chances are that you'll get auto-appointed again pretty quickly.

Otherwise, congratulations on your "powers" :)

Comment: Is there anything I need to know as an owner of the chatroom? (Also, 50 per day? I really can't shut up... :P)

Comment: You can now change the room name & description, move messages out of the room in batches (see the "room" menu in the top right -- it's not an often-used feature, though), schedule events, appoint other owners... Nothing that you'll use a lot.

Comment: Oh, btw: You only need 10 per day to be eligible. The *room* needs 50 to be considered "in need of an active owner".

Comment: Oh. I still talk a lot ;-) next order of business, rename the room to "The Land of No Choice"... :-D

Comment: @Asaf: I like the sound of that!

Comment: @balpha: It's fine that I can move messages and get noted when a messaged is flagged in any given room. Shouldn't I at least be able to delete messages in my own kingdom? :-)